# Code for command button created during runtime does not work [Excel VBA]

Tags: vba, excel, class, userform

I need to create the code for `CommandButton` that will be created during run-time. This command button is dynamic because it based on the user data.

***User_From code***

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim ctlTXT As Control

For RevNo = 1 To RevCounter

    Set ctlTXT = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")

    ctlTXT.name = RevNo
    ctlTXT.Caption = Sheet4.Range("D" & RevNo + 4).value
    ctlTXT.Left = 18
    ctlTXT.Height = 18: ctlTXT.Width = 72
    ctlTXT.Top = 15 + ((RevNo - 1) * 25)    
Next

Me.Height = (RevNo * 17) + 50

ReDim Preserve cmdArray(1 To RevNo)
Set cmdArray(RevNo).CmdEvents = ctlTXT
Set ctlTXT = Nothing

End Sub
```

***Class module Code***

```
Private Sub CmdEvents_Click()

Dim i As Integer

i = CmdEvents.name

RevisionFormPrevious.LblResponsible.Caption = Sheet4.Range("C" & i +4).value
RevisionFormPrevious.LblEdition.Caption = Sheet4.Range("D" & i + 4).value
RevisionFormPrevious.LblTelNo.Caption = Sheet4.Range("E" & i + 4).value
RevisionFormPrevious.LblFeatures.Caption = Sheet4.Range("D" & i + 4).value
RevisionFormPrevious.Features.value = Sheet4.Range("F" & i + 4).value

Load RevisionFormPrevious
RevisionFormPrevious.Show

End Sub
```

The problem is, if there are more than one button created, the code only works for the last button created. When the first and second button clicked, nothing happened.

Comment: Where is `RevCounter` declared, populated and what is its' value when called?

Comment: What is the name of your Class ? In your `Class` code you need to add at the top `Public WithEvents CmdEvents As MSForms.CommandButton`, Then, in your `Sub` you need to define it using `Dim ctlTXT As As MSForms.CommandButton`

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald RevCounter is declared as public in another module. The value when it is call is the total number of Revision available

Comment: @ShaiRado al ready declared. Sorry I did not include it in the question. Already change the ctlTXT, nothing works.

Comment: @mfo_28  nothing works is not something other users and I can help you with. You need to describe better what your code is trying to achieve, what should happen when someone clicks on the commandbutton created at runtime

Comment: You should be adding the objects to the array inside your loop, not after it.

Comment: @Rory I can say that I am a fool. Works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Each CommandButton requires its own event procedure which includes its name. In order to create this procedure you need access to the VBA-Project which is highly discouraged because any hacker could take control of your computer through that door. Therefore you have two ways to handle the problem.

1. Create as many CommandButtons as you might possibly need, each one with its own event procedure. Hide the buttons you don't immediately need and unhide and reposition them where your code now creates them.
2. Create only one button with only one event procedure but assign different values to its Caption or, possibly, Tag properties. Then program your event procedure to do different things depending upon what the Caption or Tag is when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It will be complicated to follow the first option since I don't know how many should be created since will depend on the users. Its working now.